# Como implementar un scroll infinito en javascript nativo

Tags: javascript, scroll, scrollbar

Estoy desarrollando un *scroll infinito* con **javascript nativo** (sin `jquery` u otras librerías).

La idea es que cuando el usuario scrolea hasta el final de la pagina, se ejecute una petición *fetch* con una url a un servidor.

Desarrolle el siguiente código: Declarándolo como evento sobre el Dom

`window.addEventListener('scroll',scrollInfinito,false);`

y la funcionalidad *scrollinfinito* como sigue:

```
const scrollInfinito = () => {
// ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366100/how-to-implement-infinite-scroll-using-native-javascript

// window.scrollY: Retorna el número de píxeles que han sido desplazados en el documento mediante el scroll vertical.
// offsetHeight: devuelve el alto de un elemento, incluyendo el padding vertical y los bordes, en píxeles, como un número entero.
// window.outerHeight: obtiene la altura en pixeles de toda la ventana del navegador. 
// Representa el alto de toda la ventana, incluyendo la barra de notificaciones (si se encuentra) y los bordes.
let fueEjecutado = false;

 if (
   (window.scrollY  > (document.body.offsetHeight - window.outerHeight)) &&
   fueEjecutado == false)
   {
        // console.log("It's workingg!");
        fueEjecutado = true;   
       // actualizarTabla();           
        setTimeout(() => {
            fueEjecutado = false;
    }, 50000);
}}
```

Funciona correctamente, pero el problema es que dispara varias peticiones contra el servidor. Tal vez, hay alguna forma de restringirlas o cambiar la condición por la cual se ejecuta el `scroll`. Muchas gracias!

Comment: según tengo entendido la condicional debiese ser así -> `if(document.body.offsetHeight + document.body.scrollTop >= document.body.scrollHeight) { ... }`

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/407637/no-me-funciona-el-scroll-infinito-en-navegador-movil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de `window.outerHeight` deberías usar [innerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight). Ya que [outerHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/outerHeight) nos devuelve la altura total de la ventana y para calcular si estamos al final del scroll, nos interesa el tamaño del View Port, es decir, lo que se ve en pantalla.

Deberías hacer algo así:

```
const onScroll = () => {
 if (document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight === window.scrollY) {
   // hacer fetch
   console.log('estoy en el final del scroll')
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll) // llamamos a onScroll cuando el usuario hace scroll
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me sirvio para implementar la funcionalidad. Te hago una consulta adicional, **¿Se pueden limitar la cantidad de llamadas fetch(), si se llamo una vez se puede contar y si se quiere llamar de nuevo, rechazarla?**