# No me funciona el scroll infinito en navegador movil

Tags: javascript, scroll

Espero y me puedan ayudar con este problema que tengo y no he podido solucionar, utilizo este código js para hacer el scroll infinito, todo funciona muy bien en escritorio, pero al hacer pruebas en el navegador móvil, no funciona, ya no trae información al llegar al tope del scroll. De alguna forma la condición para traer mas información al llegar al tope del scroll en móvil no se cumple, por eso no trae mas información.

```
window.onload = function() {

  var start1 = 0;
  var limit1 = 8;
  var listElm = document.getElementById('loading');
  var loadingElm = document.querySelector('.loadingimg');

  var loadMore1 = function() {

loadingElm.classList.add('show');

$.ajax({
  url:"ajax/ajax.scroll.php",
  method: "POST",
  dataType: "text",
  data: {
    getData: 1,
    start1: start1,
    limit1: limit1,
  },
    success: function(respuesta){

        start1 += limit1;

        $(".scrollbar").append(respuesta);
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        //console.log("respuesta", respuesta);

    },

     complete: function(){
       loading = false;
       loadingElm.classList.remove('show');
     }
});

  }

  window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {

    if(window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= document.documentElement.scrollHeight) {

        loadMore1();

      }

    });

  loadMore1();

}
```

Comment: Seria bueno que lo pusieras en un bloque de codigo ejecutable, la verificación la hago asi: document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight === window.scrollY puede estar relacionada con: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/276287/como-implementar-un-scroll-infinito-en-javascript-nativo?rq=1

Comment: gracias por responder @UrielManzano y perdón, pero no se como poner el código en un bloque ejecutable, ya cambie la condición por la que mencionas pero sigue igual, en escritorio al llegar al tope si trae información, pero en el navegador para móvil al llegar al tope no trae información

Answer (score 0):

te comentaba que puedes subir un bloque (fragmento) de código ejecutable, igual no tengo experiencia usándolo. Este es un ejemplo solo de html y javascript puedes probar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para pageYOffset me base de este link:[Window.scrollY](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY)
Para obtener el alto del documento scrollHeight me base en: [Tamaños de ventana y desplazamiento](https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll-window)

El codigo `scrollHeight-1` lo agregue porque cuando se ejecuta desde el bloque (fragmento) no llega al tope del scroll.

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  
  const scrollHeight = Math.max(
  document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
  document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight,
  document.body.clientHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight
   );
   console.log('pageYOffset: '+window.pageYOffset+' innerHeight: '+window.innerHeight+' scrollHeight:'+scrollHeight);
    if(window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight >= scrollHeight-1) {

        console.log('Carga con scroll');
        const img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "https://lenguajejs.com/assets/logo.svg";
img.alt = "Logo Javascript";
        document.body.appendChild(img);

      }

    });

  console.log('Carga inicial');
```

```html
<body>

<h1>Scroll en un contendor</h1>
<div>
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/440x560?text=Img+20">
 <br>
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/440x560?text=Img+20">
 <br>
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/440x560?text=Img+20">
 <br>
 <br><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/440x560?text=Img+20"><br>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/440x560?text=Img+20">
 <br>
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/440x560?text=Img+20">
 <br>
 <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/440x560?text=Img+20">
 <br>
 <br><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/440x560?text=Img+20">
 </div>

 </body>
```